# Showing $\frac{1}{f(z)}$ is holomorphic

Tags: complex-analysis

Show that if $f(z)$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\}$ and $f(z)\rightarrow\infty$ as $z\rightarrow 0$ then f has a pole at $0$

My attempt:

f is holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$ so f is holomorphic on some ball radius $r$ about $0$ denoted $B(0,r)$

we know that $f(z)\rightarrow\infty$ as $z\rightarrow 0$ so $f$ is unbounded near $0$ which implies that $\frac{1}{f(z)}\rightarrow 0$ as $z\rightarrow 0$

My question:

Do we know that $\frac{1}{f(z)}$ extends to a holomorphic function on $B(0,r)$ thus showing $0$ is a pole. Or are there better ways to think about this question!

Any help would be amazing

Comment: Yes; this is a theorem of Riemann: if a function is holomorphic on some punctured ball and bounded in that ball, then it has an analytic continuation on the entire ball.

Comment: so if $f$ has an analytic continuation in our ball then what does that say about 1/f

Comment: The theorem I mentioned is better used for $1/f$, as $f$ is not bounded on any ball containing $z = 0$, but $|f| \neq 0$ for small enough $|z|$.

Comment: how do we know 1/f is holomorphic though, im slightly confused

Comment: This is a basic property of complex differentiability. I suggest you prove this yourself; it is straightforward from the definition.

Comment: perfect thank you very much, I will give it a go!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117988/discussion-between-sven456-and-c-m).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, $0$ is an isolated singularity, then it must be a removable singularity, a pole, or an essential singularity. But if it was a removable singularity, then the limit $\lim_{z\to0}f(z)$ would be a complex number. And, if it was an essential singularity, then, by the Casorati-Weierstrass theorem, the limit $\lim_{z\to0}f(z)$ would not exist. So, it must be a pole.

Comment: so if $f$ has an essential singularity then by Casorati-Weierstrauss theorem the image of the ball $B(0,r)\setminus\{0\}$ under f is dense in $\mathbb{C}$. how can I see that the closure of the ball $B(0,r)\setminus\{0\}$ under f is not equal to $\mathbb{C}$

Comment: Since $\lim_{z\to0}f(z)=\infty$, there is some $\delta>0$ such that $|z|<\delta\implies\bigl|f(z)\bigr|>1$. So,$$f\bigl(B_\delta(0)\bigr)\subset\{z\in\Bbb C\mid|z|>1\},$$and therefore $f\bigl(B_\delta(0)\bigr)$ is not dense in $\Bbb C$.

Comment: Thank you so much!